# Git merge with conflict resolution makes a previous commit disappear

Tags: git, git-merge

We have encountered a really strange problem, which is really hard to explain, I'll do my best to illustrate.

Andy commits and pushes changes in file `build.ps1`.
Bob commits other files, and pulls.

Bob has some conflicts. Git tells him that the file `build.ps1` has changes, which I find weird because only Andy has changed it, but OK, why not.
Bob fixes the conflicts, then, knowing that he hasn't changed this file, un-stages it before his merge commit. He shouldn't have done that, but I want to understand what happens next.

The problem is that doing so has reverted the file to the previous state, and apparently removed the file's commit.

In the log: `a213826` is Bob's commit that he tries to merge; `b2067fa` is Andy's commit that disappears, and `81bcc94` is the merge commit.

```
> git log --pretty=format:'%h - %d %s (%cd) <%an>' --abbrev-commit
* 753c504 - (HEAD) ... (10/17/18 10:19:52) <Clark>
... other commits
* 81bcc94 - Merge (10/16/18 18:53:09) <Bob>
* b2067fa - build file (10/16/18 17:19:32) <Andy>
... other commits
* a213826 - members selection (10/16/18 17:35:46) <Bob>
... other commits
```

In `a213826`, we can see that Bob has changed some files:

```
> git show --name-status a213826
commit a2138265ba464afed6955f7a2976b9d868c6449e
Author: Bob
Date:   Tue Oct 16 17:35:46 2018 +0200
    members selection
M       Viewer3D.DataAccess/DataAccess.cs
M       Viewer3D.DataAccess/IDataAccess.cs
M       Viewer3D/Content/view-panel.css
M       Viewer3D/Controllers/DirectoryController.cs
M       Viewer3D/Controllers/NotesController.cs
M       Viewer3D/Scripts/class-panel.js
M       Viewer3D/Scripts/view-panel-note-form.js
M       Viewer3D/Views/Home/_PanelNotes.cshtml
```

In `81bcc94`, we can see that that in the merge, Bob has resolved some conflicts, but the `build.ps1` file has not been modified:

```
> git show --name-status 81bcc94
commit 81bcc94cbe26859ca6b02d2908f6afc64aec1701
Merge: a213826 b2067fa
Author: Bob
Date:   Tue Oct 16 18:53:09 2018 +0200
    Merge
MM      Viewer3D.DataAccess/DataAccess.cs
MM      Viewer3D.DataAccess/IDataAccess.cs
MM      Viewer3D/Content/view-panel.css
MM      Viewer3D/Controllers/NotesController.cs
MM      Viewer3D/Scripts/view-panel-note-form.js
```

However, Tortoise Git tells a very different story, and show the `build.ps1` file as modified!

[image: git merge]

In the file's `git log`, the `b2067fa` commit does not appear anymore:

```
> git log -p -- .\build_psake.ps1
commit 2d5eef1d1a13508621afe99bad8a2af05f3cc298
Author: Andy
Date:   Tue Sep 4 15:25:12 2018 +0200
    changes build path
(some diff)

commit 23dd900f71e88053b333b886491a2b5a9b971291
Author: Clark
Date:   Mon Jun 18 09:19:34 2018 +0000
...
```

However, if we `log --follow`, the commit appears again:

```
> git log --follow -p -- .\build_psake.ps1
commit b2067fac01e9b8d8ee4d6a88a91f4fd994efdf9e
Author: Andy
Date:   Tue Oct 16 17:19:32 2018 +0200
    build file
(some diff)

commit 2d5eef1d1a13508621afe99bad8a2af05f3cc298
Author: Andy
Date:   Tue Sep 4 15:25:12 2018 +0200
    changes build path
....
```

---

So, my questions:

- Why does Git tells Bob that file A has changed? Shouldn't the corresponding commit have been merged silently?
- What has made the commit disappear from the file's "simple log", but not in the "follow log"?
- Why do git tells me that the file hasn't been changed in the log, but Tortoise Git tells me the opposite?

Please help me make sense of it all!

Comment: For your first point, you might want to consider where (at which commit) Bob's local branch (I guess they both work on the same branch since you're not mentionning any specific workflow) was when he pulled. The last common parent *could* very well be quite far in the history, thus inducing some changes. (If we were to imagine what *should* have been done, Bob should have pulled before merging his changes in.)

Comment: @RomainValeri there are about 20 commits between Bob's commit and his merge, but none of them touch the `build.ps1` file. It hadn't changed for a few months.

Answer (score 2):

During the merge, Bob unstaged the diffs from Andy on build.ps1, didn't he?

So if you look at the main branch, coming from Bob, there is no more change from Andy's commit. If you had to look from Andy's perspective, you would see Andy adding and Bob removing the change.

There may have been some local change on Bob's box, perhaps line endings?